# No static method isTraceInProgress()Z in class Landroidx/compose/runtime/ComposerKt Error Jetpack Compose using Google Maps

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I don't know why I'm getting this error when I try using Google Maps with jetpack compose version 1.1.1, The app crash and doesn't launch, and when I remove the Google Maps code it works fine without any issues! I don't understand this error and don't know how to fix it!

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.emmanuel.japh, PID: 6095
        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isTraceInProgress()Z in class Landroidx/compose/runtime/ComposerKt; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt' appears in /data/app/~~CawNWHnzOeevtc9GLdJ9Wg==/com.emmanuel.japh-hZxyKg3RuIgGoJA8QHMO8A==/base.apk)
            at com.google.maps.android.compose.GoogleMapKt.GoogleMap(Unknown Source:6)
            at com.emmanuel.japh.ui.screens.HomeScreenKt.HomeScreen(HomeScreen.kt:20)
            at com.emmanuel.japh.navigation.ComposableSingletons$BottomNavGraphKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(BottomNavGraph.kt:23)
            at com.emmanuel.japh.navigation.ComposableSingletons$BottomNavGraphKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(BottomNavGraph.kt:22)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
            at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4$2.invoke(NavHost.kt:163)
            at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4$2.invoke(NavHost.kt:162)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:84)
            at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:60)
            at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.access$SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:1)
            at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:52)
            at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:51)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
            at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.LocalOwnersProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:47)
            at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(NavHost.kt:162)
            at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(NavHost.kt:141)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
            at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$4$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:115)
            at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$4$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:110)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
            at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt.Crossfade(Crossfade.kt:124)
            at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt.Crossfade(Crossfade.kt:55)
            at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:141)
            at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$5.invoke(Unknown Source:13)
            at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$5.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:140)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2158)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2404)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2585)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2571)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:247)
            at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
```

My Home Screen

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen()
{
    val singapore = LatLng(1.35, 103.87)
    val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
        position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(singapore, 10f)
    }
    GoogleMap(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState
    ) {
        Marker(
            state = MarkerState(position = singapore),
            title = "Singapore",
            snippet = "Marker in Singapore"
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, but compose 1.2.x, Maps Compose 1.3.0 or higher seems to solve the problem.
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose/issues/67

Comment: I was faced same issue. But below version works for me.

`compose_version = "1.2.0-rc03"`
`compose_maps_version = "2.5.3"`